# SPRESENSE Arduino IDEでの「dtostrf」サポートについて

Tags: spresense, arduino

SPRESENSE Arduino IDE（Ver1.8.16）でプログラム作成をしています。

Arduino言語でfloatやdoubleの値を書式付ける時によく使用する `dtostrf` という関数ですが、以下のコンパイルエラーが出ます。

```
dtostrf_test:13:24: error: 'dtostrf' was not declared in this scope
      dtostrf(val1, 3, 1, s);
                           ^
exit status 1
'dtostrf' was not declared in this scope
```

Arduino言語では `sprintf` 関数がfloat／doubleに対応していないので、`dtostrf` をよく使用するのですが、SPRESENSE のライブラリーではサポートしていないのでしょうか？

使用例：

```c
char s[7];
char t[7];
char buf[20];
float val1 = -10.254;
float val2 = 97.623;
dtostrf(val1, 3, 1, s);
dtostrf(val2, 3, 1, t);
sprintf(buf, "%s,%s", s, t );
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

**その①**
sprintfが浮動小数点をサポートしているので、dtostrfを使わずに実装する。

```c
  sprintf(buf, "%3.1f,%3.1f", val1, val2);
```

**その②**
Stringクラスを使って文字列に変換する。

```c
  String ss(val1, 1);
  String tt(val2, 1);
  sprintf(buf, "%s,%s", ss.c_str(), tt.c_str());
```

**その③**
すでにdtostrfが多用されていて置き換えるのが難しい場合は、
Stringクラスにあるdtostrf関数を抜き出してローカルに定義してそれを利用する。

```c
#ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_SPRESENSE
char * dtostrf(double value, unsigned int width, unsigned int decimalPlaces, char* buf)
{
  char fmt[20];

  snprintf(fmt, 20, "%%%d.%df", width, decimalPlaces);
  sprintf(buf, fmt, value);
  return buf;
}
#endif
```

個人的には、dtostrfが特殊すぎるので、
一般的なC言語標準ライブラリの使い方である①がおススメです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
ArduinoのC++言語は特殊で、sprintf関数でfloat／doubleに対応していないので、記載いただいた「その１」は使用できません。（その代替えとしてdtostrfが実装されている様で。。）
dtostrfを使ったソースを移し替えていてひっかかりました。
「その２」のStringクラスは使用したのですが、書き換えが面倒なのでdtostrfのエラーが消えたら楽かと思い、こちらで聞いてみました。
貴重なアドバイスをいただきありがとうございました。

Comment: なるほど。ArduinoとSPRESENSEとで共通プログラムにしたいということですね。「その3」の関数を #ifdef ARDUINO_ARCH_SPRESENSE ~ #endif で囲んでみました。これでどちらの環境でもコンパイルできるようになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！。こちらで試してみます。